# Unable to import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber and error in @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

Tags: cucumber, appium, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Following is the code of TestRunner.

**TestRunner.class**

```
package com.run;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Working fine when I updated the cucumber-junit & cucumber-java version to 1.2.0

Comment: It could be a good idea to use the latest version, 1.2.5